# Server Side Memory leak when calling Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, memory-leaks, server-side

I have two very simple web service methods ,I call every second using json
there is a memory leak in IIS, the w3wp process takes up 300-400k a second
what can be done to stop the leak?

the methods are as below:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<StationStatus> GetAllStationsValues(string networkID ,string stationIDs)
{
    List<StationStatus> stationStats = new List<StationStatus>();
    foreach (string stationID in stationIDs.Split(','))
    {
        if (Application[networkID + "-" + stationID] != null)
        {
            string[] vals = (string[])Application[networkID + "-" + stationID];

            stationStats.Add(new StationStatus() { NetworkID = networkID, StationID = stationID, ComponentName = vals[0].Split(':')[0], LatestValue = vals[0].Split(':')[1], Status = "0" });////////
        }
    }

    return stationStats;
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetValue(string networkID, string stationID)
{
    int sec = DateTime.Now.Second;

    if (Application[networkID + "-" + stationID] == null)
    {
        return "";
    }

    string[] compValues = (string[])Application[networkID + "-" + stationID];


    string returnValue = "";

    foreach (string compValue in compValues)
    {
        returnValue += compValue + ",";
    }

    return returnValue.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Comment: What is the Application class, and the StationStatus class? Can you add the code for them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class for appending to your returnValue string.